# saprfc extension for php is not working

Tags: php, saprfc

I am a SAP-ABAP begginer and I need to fetch the data from SAP through PHP for my company need.

I have installe:

- WAMP Version 2.2
- Apache Version : 2.2.22
- PHP Version    : 5.3.13
- SAPRFC Version is 1.4.1

Added php_saprfc_530.dll to the php ext directory and added extension to php.ini

On restart of Apache, application event reported this error:

> PHP Startup: saprfc: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS PHP compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC6

I have been struggling with this error for the past two days. How can I fix it?

Comment: You have struggled for two days? What did you try?

Comment: @user2056910 I think this binary compiler incompatibility, make sure that `SAPRFC` and `PHP` were compiled with some compiler.

Comment: Under **Windows XP**, this combination worked for me:
**apache: 2.2.8, php : 5.2.5, saprfc: php_saprfc_528.dll**

Comment: I'm also struggling with this... did you find any solution?

Comment: if you're using centos or other linux, try install php5-devel and gcc then recompile (phpize and ./configure)